# SSRS Parameter value based on other Parameter value not working using LEFT

Tags: reporting-services

I have an issue with SSRS parameters. I have a parameter that is based on a dataset value. This parameter is called UserOffice and correctly returns value GB10. I have a second parameter called IncludePrimary that returns the value of UserOffice (=Parameters!UserOffice.Value):
[image]

I then change the value of the IncludePrimary expression to be the first 2 characters of UserOffice (=Left(Parameters!UserOffice.Value, 2)):
[image]

I expected the field to show GB. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: A parameter does not *return* a value. It can have available values and default values. How are these set for your second parameter?

Comment: I am assigning the values for the second parameter via the Default Value field. Nothing in the Available Values section. If the Default Value is =Parameters!UserOffice.Value then it works fine, if the Default Value is =Left(Parameters!UserOffice.Value, 2) then it does not return anything.

Comment: If the Available Values do not depend on the first parameter, the second parameter will not get updated automatically at all. If you don't use Available Values at all, then every value will still be a feasible value after the first parameter changed, so again, the value will not change. You must use Available Values and restrict them to only that one value `=Left(Parameters!UserOffice.Value, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

A parameter (your second one) isn't "updated" (the default value isn't re-applied) while the currently selected value(s) is (are) still in the list of available values after other parameters have been changed.

To update the second parameter, you must not only change its Default Value but will need to set its Available Values as well:

[image: Available Values]

Or, of course, you can simply use your expression `Left(Parameters!UserOffice.Value, 2)` whenever you need it, so you don't need that second parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied. They responses were very helpful. In order to resolve my issue I created a second dataset that calculated the default value (Y or N). I used set Available Values and then used my new dataset to set the default.

It works a treat.

Rob